# Create L2TP/IPSec VPN base on VpnService programmatically in Android

Tags: android, vpn

I have searched for a day , about create L2TP/IPSec VPN base on VpnService . But there is no matched result .
With LocalVPN (https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN ) , I can create a VPN(OpenVPN) android app base on VPNService . But i want to create a L2TP/IPSec VPN Android App  .

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Are you talking about creating the client or host?

Comment: Sorry , i'm talking about Android App . I will add that information .

Comment: @JackLong were you able to do it?

Comment: @JackLong any luck here??

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Simply cannot be done.

The VPNService does not allow you to create a profile with username and password and there is no support for creating a L2TP or PPTP programmatically. Lots of people have been looking for this but Google are just not sharing their toys.

Even attempting to use the Hidden API has no support. Many VPN apps out there default to use [OpenVPN-ICS](https://github.com/schwabe/openvpn) or IKEV2([strongSwan](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan)) or require you to manually create the L2TP/ PPTP VPN connection on the device yourself.

Many people have requested this from Google but they either get a message saying the request is now obsolete or it is not financially viable.

Comment: hi bro, re you sure this info ?