# Create L2TP/IPSec client android

Tags: android, vpn, ipsec

I need to create a L2TP/IPSec client application android. I read the [android VPN documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn). It states some legacy API for that. But I could not find such one. Also provided example app for VPN client does not work since it was built for a very old version. Android has built-in support on this VPN protocol. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278313/create-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-base-on-vpnservice-programmatically-in-android) says no official API. However, I have seen applications which support IPsec directly. how to call it in VpnService class as stated in the official documentation. Also if I need to add custom VPN protocol how to run and get those interfaces from java code?